# How to save updated data in UIAlertViewController to server?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I have a problem in my UIAlertViewController in that 3 UITextFields in that what the user edited that data store to server. how can i do that?
here is my code

```
-(IBAction)changePswd:(id)sender
{
UIAlertController *alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Your Password" message:@"Here !" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
__block typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
 {
     textField.tag = 100;
     textField.delegate = weakSelf;
     textField.placeholder = @"Old Password";
     textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
 }];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
 {
     textField.tag = 101;
     textField.delegate = weakSelf;
     textField.placeholder = @"New Password";
     textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
 }];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
 {
     textField.tag = 102;
     textField.delegate = weakSelf;
     textField.placeholder = @"Conform Password";
     textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
 }];
UIAlertAction *submitAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
                               {
                                   MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
                                   HUD.labelText =@"Updating Please Wait...";
                                   [self.view addSubview:HUD];
                                   [HUD show:YES];
                                   [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(submitDetails) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

                               }];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
{

}];
[alert addAction:cancelAction];
[alert addAction:submitAction];
 [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When i press the submit  button what the user entered text that will match by old data and update with new data.
here is my webservice method,

```
-(NSData *)resetPassword: (NSString *)password andNewPassword:(NSString *)pswd andUserId:(NSString *)userId
{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Api"];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:RESETPASSWORD,password,pswd,userId];
NSData *myJSONData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myJSONData]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
return returnData;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?  What does `submitDetails` do?

Comment: if the user enter the text into textfield! i want to store that data in my server ?

Comment: That's not a problem; that's a feature specification.  Do you call `resetPassword`?  Does it work?  If not, what goes wrong?  And, again, what does `submitDetails` do?

Comment: Sorry i forgot this methods -(void)submitDetails
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(profile) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
-(void)profile
{
    NSData *returnData;
   returnData=[[WebServices alloc]resetPassword: andNewPassword: andUserId:];
    
}
here webservices is a class?